# Scheduling zoom meeting with Outlook calendar API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I am trying to schedule an online zoom meeting event using the outlook calendar API. I have installed the zoom add-ins in the outlook calendar. From the UI level going to the outlook calendar, I can schedule a zoom meeting on the outlook calendar.
The question is:

1. How can I achieve the same using the **outlook calendar API**? For other online meeting providers like Skype, I have successfully created an online meeting via API. Was wondering about zoom.

Also, As mentioned in the docs:

> An organization that supports any of the following online meeting
> providers can set up Outlook calendars and enable organizing meetings
> online:
>
> Microsoft Teams, acquired as part of a Microsoft 365 business or
> enterprise suite
> Skype  Skype for Business (which is being superceded by Microsoft
> Teams)

2. Does this mean, while creating an online meeting via API only these three online meeting providers can be used?
3. When I query using Microsoft Graph API explorer for endpoint `/me/calendar`. Zoom add-in is not included within `allowedOnlineMeetingProviders`. Are there any steps required to add zoom in `allowedOnlineMeetingProviders`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-online-meetings?tabs=http#calendars-and-online-meeting-providers)
currently, there are 3 providers supported and they are

1. Microsoft Teams, acquired as part of a Microsoft 365 business or enterprise suite
2. Skype
3. Skype for Business (which is being superseded by Microsoft Teams)

Do watch this documentation to see if zoom will be supported later on. You can also raise a feature request for zoom as a provider support over [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)